# tabular with xticks enabled at some plots make one plot moved

Tags: pgfplots, plot, groupplots

I have 4 plots arranged using tabular:

[image: resulting document]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
  height=4cm, width=\linewidth*0.5,
  every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none},
  xmin=-1, xmax=1, domain=-1:1, samples=100, minor y tick num=1,
  xtick=\empty
}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left]
    \begin{axis}[title=Gaussian,
      legend entries={$s=2$, $s=4$,$s=8$}]
      \addplot {exp(- (2*x)^2)};
      \addplot {exp(- (4*x)^2)};
      \addplot {exp(- (8*x)^2)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis right]
      \begin{axis}[title=Volume Splines]
        \addplot {abs(x)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \\
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left]
    \begin{axis}[title=Multi Quadrics,
      legend entries={$s=2$, $s=4$,$s=6$},
      xtick={}]
      \addplot {sqrt(2^2 + x^2)};
      \addplot {sqrt(4^2 + x^2)};
      \addplot {sqrt(6^2 + x^2)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis right]
      \begin{axis}[title=Inverse Multi Quadrics,
        legend entries={$s=1$, $s=2$,$s=3$},
        xtick={}]
        \addplot {1/sqrt(1^2 + x^2)};
        \addplot {1/sqrt(2^2 + x^2)};
        \addplot {1/sqrt(3^2 + x^2)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the lower left plot is slightly moved to the left. How can I fix that?

Why I don't use `groupplots`? I want different legends for each of the plots, as you can see. AFAIK this is not possible with `groupplots`.

Why I don't use `matrix`? According to pgfplots documentation 4.19.4 with matrix you need to use `legend to name`.

If it's possible with either one of the other two methods, I happily stand corrected.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is in the y-axis in your bottom-left figure. It contains `2`, `4` and `6`. But for your top-left figure, it contains a `0.5`, and there is additional space for the extra `0.` part.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Would you be open to use `groupplots` for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The groupplot library is made for this.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
  height=4cm, width=\linewidth*0.5,
  every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none},
  xmin=-1, xmax=1, domain=-1:1, samples=100, minor y tick num=1,
  xtick=\empty
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2},height=4cm, width=\linewidth*0.5,]
    \nextgroupplot[title=Gaussian,
      legend entries={$s=2$, $s=4$,$s=8$}]
      \addplot {exp(- (2*x)^2)};
      \addplot {exp(- (4*x)^2)};
      \addplot {exp(- (8*x)^2)};
     \nextgroupplot[title=Volume Splines]
        \addplot {abs(x)};
     \nextgroupplot[title=Multi Quadrics,
      legend entries={$s=2$, $s=4$,$s=6$},
      xtick={}]
      \addplot {sqrt(2^2 + x^2)};
      \addplot {sqrt(4^2 + x^2)};
      \addplot {sqrt(6^2 + x^2)};
     \nextgroupplot[title=Inverse Multi Quadrics,
        legend entries={$s=1$, $s=2$,$s=3$},
        xtick={}]
        \addplot {1/sqrt(1^2 + x^2)};
        \addplot {1/sqrt(2^2 + x^2)};
        \addplot {1/sqrt(3^2 + x^2)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lovely! Not sure why I said that `groupplot` is not suitable. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `\begin{tabular}{ll}`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
  height=4cm, width=\linewidth*0.5,
  every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none},
  xmin=-1, xmax=1, domain=-1:1, samples=100, minor y tick num=1,
  xtick=\empty
}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left]
    \begin{axis}[title=Gaussian,
      legend entries={$s=2$, $s=4$,$s=8$}]
      \addplot {exp(- (2*x)^2)};
      \addplot {exp(- (4*x)^2)};
      \addplot {exp(- (8*x)^2)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis right]
      \begin{axis}[title=Volume Splines]
        \addplot {abs(x)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \\
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left]
    \begin{axis}[title=Multi Quadrics,
      legend entries={$s=2$, $s=4$,$s=6$},
      xtick={}]
      \addplot {sqrt(2^2 + x^2)};
      \addplot {sqrt(4^2 + x^2)};
      \addplot {sqrt(6^2 + x^2)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis right]
      \begin{axis}[title=Inverse Multi Quadrics,
        legend entries={$s=1$, $s=2$,$s=3$},
        xtick={}]
        \addplot {1/sqrt(1^2 + x^2)};
        \addplot {1/sqrt(2^2 + x^2)};
        \addplot {1/sqrt(3^2 + x^2)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: figure aligned]

Comment: @marmot Agreed. I don’t think the OP is aware of still being able to create different legends with `groupplots`. I took that as a “no” for using `groupplots`.

Comment: I agree with you. Honestly, I did not read the question that far. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I should mark both as a valid answer. I prefer `groupplot` though, don't know why I thought that different legends where not possible.